# App built with ReTool in production for users

Tags: retool

I have a colleague who built a database app using ReTool.
Since it has been built quite nice, we would like to publish it on our cloud space and make it accessible for more than just him.

But we can't find any information on how to publish the app, apart from the in-app settings, to publish it, but it is always a "preview" version.

Anyone has experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share your Retool app publicly via a public link, and embed it in an iFrame in other applications or web pages. In edit mode just click the "Share" button on the top right and select the "Public" tab. (This will render your app publicly.)

But It's good to know that the public apps are only available on the Business and Enterprise plans.

Check this [link](https://docs.retool.com/docs/embedding-retool#public-apps) for detailed information.

You can also get the share app url from **(...)** menu.
[image: Share app screen]

Comment: Oh... nice. Well then I built an app in ReTool which only a handful of people can use. At least now I know, how it should be built and can now rebuild it without tools.